# Express the complex number in rectangular form $a + ib$

Tags: complex-numbers

$12e^{2-\pi*i/3}$ express this in rectangular form $a + i\cdot b$

Not sure how to solve when fractions are involved

Example $2.6\cdot e^{3+i} = 2.6\cdot e^3\cdot e^i$ ?

Comment: You might want to visit the following site to see how to format your question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.  As it is, your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$12e^{2-i\pi/3}=12e^2e^{-i\pi/3}$$ Now use $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ to find that remaining exponential.

Answer (score 0):

Might be useful to think of the desired answer as $$a+ib=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)=re^{i\theta}$$
where $a=r\cos\theta, b=r\sin\theta$.

Also, note that 
$$ke^{p+i\theta}=ke^p\cdot e^{i\theta}=re^{i\theta}$$

where $r=ke^p$ is a real number (assuming $k$ is real).

That should get you going.